# Excel Allow Users to Edit Ranges using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to specify the users who may edit a range without a password using vba?

I was thinking about having a Permissions sheet with a list of the usernames in column A and the ranges in row 1. At the intersection of a username and range a Y would indicate permission. Then via vba the Allow Users to Edit Ranges would be modified accordingly to allow the user to edit the range without a password. If the intersection has a N then the username would be removed from the list of users who may edit the range without a password rather than just changing their permission to Deny

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was fascinated by your idea. Therefore the solution I came up with is a little complicated. It presumes that you want to allocate access permissions to only one worksheet. If there are several expansion is required. Paste this code in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the action.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 25 Jan 2018

    Dim Deny As Long
    Dim Msg As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Deny = Target.Cells.Count
    If Err Or Deny > 1 Then
        Msg = "Please edit only one cell at a time."
    End If

    ' cells which are unlocked may be modified by anyone
    If (Deny = 1) And (Target.Locked = True) Then
        If DenyAccess(Target) Then
            Msg = "You are not permitted to modify this cell."
        End If
    End If

    If Len(Msg) Then
        MsgBox Msg & vbCr & _
               "The change you made will be reversed.", _
               vbInformation, "Invalid modification"
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The rest of the code should be in a normal code module. It doesn't exist. You will have to create it. The default name will be `Module1`. Rename it to suit your preference.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim MyPass As Range

Function DenyAccess(Target As Range) As Boolean
    ' 25 Jan 2018

    ' restart Excel after making changes to the Permissions
    If MyPass Is Nothing Then                   ' use existing if already loaded
        Set MyPass = GetPermissions
        If MyPass Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' no permissions found
    End If
    DenyAccess = (Application.Intersect(Target, MyPass) Is Nothing)
End Function

Private Function GetPermissions() As Variant
    ' 25 Jan 2018
    ' returns a range object
    ' return Nothing if no valid permissions were found

    Dim Fun() As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim C As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Permissions")              ' sheet for which acces is to be granted
    Arr = UserDataRange
    If VarType(Arr) = 8204 Then
        ReDim Fun(UBound(Arr, 2))
        For C = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Fun(i) = Ws.Range(Arr(1, C))
            If Err = 0 Then i = i + 1
        Next C

        If Not Fun(0) Is Nothing Then
            ReDim Preserve Fun(i - 1)

            For C = 1 To UBound(Fun)
                Set Fun(0) = Application.Union(Fun(0), Fun(C))
            Next C
        End If
        Set GetPermissions = Fun(0)
    Else
        Set GetPermissions = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Private Function UserDataRange() As Variant
    ' 25 Jan 2018
    ' returns an array lifted from the worksheet

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Permissions")              ' sheet where the permissions are
                                                    ' User names in column A
    With Application
        On Error Resume Next
        R = .Match(.UserName, Ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    If R Then
        With Ws
            UserDataRange = Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Now you need to create a worksheet with the permissions. No Y and N, as you suggested yourself, just the username in column A and ranges in the following columns, like "A1", "B2:C3", "F2" etc, one range in one cell (no commas). Be sure to write the user names exactly as they are stored in each user's computer. The code doesn't forgive blank spaces (as I found out) and I think it might even be case sensitive (you may like to find out, lol:). If you have this sheet in the workbook, make it `xlVeryHidden` and password-protect the VBA project. (Not safe but more difficult.)

The final step is to prepare your worksheet for action. Cells which are to be controlled by the `Permissions` must be locked. Access will be denied by default for any cell which is locked and not permitted. Modification is allowed by anyone if the cell is unlocked.

Note that the permissions are read only on first use and then stored in memory. (That is the task of the global variable `MyPass`. If you modify the permissions the new settings will not take effect until you restart Excel. This is done in the interest speed: VBA mustn't check the permissions worksheet for every modification.

I hope it works as designed.